# running python in an argument of a program & how to give hex when string expected

Tags: python, bash

I've come across this command and want to understand how it works. `program` is just simple c program command for mac or linux.

```
./program `python -c 'print "\xC8\xCE\xC5\x06"'`
```

1) Can someone explain how this command works?

2) is this the only way to give a hex value to a program when string is expected?

Comment: what do you mean by you "recently saw a command"? are you on windows? mac? did you run that command? is it a public computer? do you suspect someone hacked you? yo dawg, we need context.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is running c and sending arguments by python

Comment: so, I know the results but I want to know how ` ` in the shell works and what python -c is (the c option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of evaluating python expressions from the command line in bash. It has nothing to do with C. The only python code here is `print "\xC8\xCE\xC5\x06"`. The rest is bash code.

You can try this command in bash `python -c "print 'Hello World'"`

You can also read `man python` for more information on python command line flags.

In python strings `\xHH` is used to translate a hex value into characters. In this case `u"\xC8\xCE\xC5" == u"ÈÎÅ"`. If you don't use unicode strings, the output will be some non-ascii characters, which `program` might make sense of, but that cannot be entered or printed in a regular bash session. `program` might not care if the string is printable, and instead just treat it as binary data.

The backticks in bash will run the enclosed command first, and then use the string as a regular bash expression in the parent scope. Another way of doing this in bash would be this:

```
./program $(python -c "print '\xC8\xCE\xC5\x06'")
```

To answer you second question: There are other ways of doing this as well. You could probably use printf instead of python. Like this:

```
 ./program $(printf "\xC8\xCE\xC5\x06")
```